# NMOS with gate source shorted and negative threshold voltage

Tags: mosfet, homework

[image]

First of all is it really possible to have a nmos with negative threshold voltage? If threshold voltage for M1 was positive, then M1 would be in cutoff. How do I analyze this circuit?

Comment: I see two solutions: 1) M1 is a **depletion type** NMOS. 2) M1 is drawn incorrectly and should have been a PMOS. But think what happens when V1 = 5 V, what will M2 do?

Comment: You mean that enhancement nmos cannot have negative threshold voltage? If it is depletion type, then how do I solve it?

Comment: Since V1 = Vgs2 = 5 V > 1V, I assume M2 is in saturation. I find Id which comes out to be 0.8 mA. Now I need to verify that Vds2 > 4V or else Id I have found is wrong. How do I get Vds2 now?

Comment: *Since V1 = Vgs2 = 5 V > 1V, I assume M2 is in saturation* If M2 is in saturation, its Vds > Vds,sat. How much is Vds,sat when Vgs = 5 V? Is that going to happen in this circuit?

Comment: Vds,sat will be 4v for Vgs = 5V and Vth=1v. To get Vds > 4 (Vds,sat), I would need M1 to be shorted?

Answer (score 2):

> First of all is it really possible to have a nmos with negative
>   threshold voltage?

Yes, it's called a depletion mode MOSFET and, in your diagram, the MOSFET symbol is a depletion mode MOSFET: -

[image]

As wired in your schematic, M1 (being a depletion type MOSFET) is acting as a constant current source.

Picture from [this document](https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/IntroDepletionModeMOSFET.pdf) entitled "An introduction to Depletion-mode MOSFETs".

An example of a depletion mode MOSFET is the [BSS126](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSS126-DS-v02_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304330f6860601310483af163eba).

Comment: Current source? Isnt this an NMOS inverter with depletion type load. M2 is in saturation region and M1 is in linear region?

Comment: No, M1 will be in saturation region i.e. acting like a current source. For a MOSFET, the linear region is equivalent to the saturation region of a BJT so you may be getting your terms back-to-front? M2 may be in its saturation region but, your basic circuit doesn't have enough detail to definitively state this.